# How can I remove newline character (\n) at the end of Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter GUI.

I am wondering how can I remove newline character (\n) at the end of Text widget? It's making my App looking ugly I don't want this.

Example code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title('Advanced Calculator v0.9')
window.geometry('500x400')
window.resizable(False, False)

window.configure(background='black')

hist_t = Text(window, background='black', height='7', foreground='red', font='Verdana', highlightcolor='grey', highlightthickness=1, relief='solid')

Label(window, text='History:', background='black', foreground='red').pack(pady=3, anchor='w')

hist_t.pack(fill='x', padx=3)

hist_t.insert('end', '4 + 4 = 8\n2 + 2 = 4\n5 + 3 = 8\n10 + 13 = 23\n30 + 10 = 40\n12 + 8 = 20')

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `rstrip()`? Why does a newline make your app ugly? It's just an empty line. Or do you actually have a `\ ` and `n` character pair in your Text widget? If so, you need to post a [mcve] that reproduces this problem.

Comment: If you only want 6 lines, why do you set the height to 7?

Comment: The problem is, whenever I add some text to it, there is always empty line at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem doesn't appear to be any extra newlines, it's simply that you configured it to show 7 lines but you're only inserting 6. If you set the height to 6 you won't see this blank  line.

Comment: My Commit button is only enabled if the original value (<foobar foobar>) is different to the current value. The current value should be initialized as  <foobar foobar>. Unfortunately, tkinter initializes this as <foobar footer\n> thus causing the Commit button to be incorrectly enabled. Obviously, changing the height of the text box has no effect on this. 
The only sound solution is to remove any trailing newline whenever tk.Text.get is called. (It is necessary to test for a trailing newline otherwise the code will be broken if tkinter ever gets fixed)

Comment: @lemi57ssss: yes, tkinter guarantees that there will always be a newline as the last character. You don't need to remove any trailing newlines. Instead, just get all the text up to but not including the final character (eg: `text.get("1.0", "end-1c")`). That is the accepted way to get all of the text in a text widget. Tkinter won't ever get "fixed" because this is how it is defined to work.

Answer (score 2):

Assert:

```
hist_t = tk.Text(...)
```

You can always call `hist_t.delete('end-1c', 'end')` whenever you want to remove the last char, which is newline in this case. You can also remove the last char only if it is newline:

```
while hist_t.get('end-1c', 'end') == '\n':
    hist_t.delete('end-1c', 'end')
```

Comment: It is impossible to remove the final newline that is automatically added by the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Textbox always inserts a blank line at the end. The problem was compounded when editing textbox and yet another blank line was inserted. However during edit you could remove blank lines so you can't use `"end-1c"` all the time.

The trick was to remove 1 or more extra blank lines after editing:

```
# Rebuild lyrics from textbox
self.work_lyrics_score = \
    self.lyrics_score_box.get('1.0', tk.END)
while self.work_lyrics_score.endswith('\n\n'):
    # Drop last blank line which textbox automatically inserts.
    # User may have manually deleted during edit so don't always assume
    self.work_lyrics_score = self.work_lyrics_score[:-1]
```

Note however this is with Linux. For Windows you might need something like:

```
while self.work_lyrics_score.endswith('\n\r\n\r'):
    # Drop last blank line which textbox automatically inserts.
    # User may have manually deleted during edit so don't always assume
    self.work_lyrics_score = self.work_lyrics_score[:-2]
```

Or whatever the the control code is for DOS/Windows LF/CR (Line Feed / Carriage Return) typewriter days style is.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, whenever I add some text to it, **there is always
> empty line at the end**.

The problem can be fixed.

The Easier way to do.

- Using `Counter` from the library to count the number of newlines.
- Add variable and add to the keyword `height=num_of_n+1` in `Text` widget.
- Do not add string inside the `hist_t.insert` parameter. Use variables
  to pass.

That is all. So easily Python can do for you.

Snippet:

```
:
:
data_n = '4 + 4 = 8\n2 + 2 = 4\n5 + 3 = 8\n10 + 13 = 23\n30 + 10 = 40\n12 + 8 = 20'
data = Counter(data_n) 
num_of_n = data['\n'] 
print(num_of_n)
 

    
hist_t = Text(window, background='black', height=num_of_n+1,...
:
:
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Btw, You can add more newlines.