# How to remove nextline in a textbox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, text-files

How to remove the next line in a multiline text(textbox). Every time I save to the textfile the radio button value is keep going to the next line
 here is my write code

```
def save():
    with open('StudentInfo', 'w') as f:
         f.write(f"\n{inputA.get()},{inputB.get()},{inputC.get()},{t.get('1.0',END)},{var.get()}")
         f.close()
```

and here is what I write when I save to the next line.

```
123,qwe,qwe,qwe
,Female    #this is from the radio button and keep going to the next line
```

Comment: Do you get what you want if you drop the ```"\n"``` from ```f.write```?

Comment: This have to be: `t.get('1.0', 'end -1c')`. Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), section **Expressions**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove newline character (\n) at the end of Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220788/how-can-i-remove-newline-character-n-at-the-end-of-text-widget)

Answer (score 3):

The text widget automatically adds a trailing newline after the last character in the widget. To get everything up to but not including this automatic trailing newline, use the index "end-1c" ("end" minus one character). That will result in getting exactly what the user entered.

```
t.get('1.0',"end-1c")
```